# Production connectivity issue to WebApi Project using Breeze + Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, breeze, hottowel

I have implement a project using John Papa's [HotTowel](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/build-apps-angular-breeze) example with Breeze  & Angular.

I have two application.

- App.Web
- App.WebApis

In my local environment they work great and running on different ports:

- App.Web (localhost:{port1})
- App.WebApis ( localhost: 59063)

When I pushed the code out to production, I created two web application in IIS w/ following bindings

- App.Web (domain: www.{mydoman}.com, port: 80}
- App.WebApis (domain: localhost, port: 59063}

When I run the app, I get the following error:

```
[OTG Error] Error retrieving data.Metadata query failed for: http://localhost:59063/breeze/Breeze/Metadata; HTTP response status 0 and no message.  Likely did not or could not reach server. Is the server running? Error: Metadata query failed for: http://localhost:59063/breeze/Breeze/Metadata; HTTP response status 0 and no message.  Likely did not or could not reach server. Is the server running?
```

Here is what I have done so far:

Under Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs

```
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new BreezeSimpleCorsHandler());
```

Here is the BreezeSimpleCorsHandler.cs:

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;

using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Breeze.WebApi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Global message handler for CORS support (Development Only)
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Simple-minded, allow-everything, Web API message handler
    /// for CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)
    /// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
    /// Accepts any request for any action from any site
    /// Warning: Do not use for production code. Use as inspiration for a
    /// solution that is consistent with your security requirements.
    /// Code copied with minor changes from 
    /// http://blog.bittercoder.com/2012/09/09/cors-and-webapi/
    /// Install early in Web Api Pipeline, 
    /// perhaps in Global.asax or BreezeWebApiConfig
    /// Set "runaAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" in Web.config for < IIS 8    
    /// </remarks>
    /// <example>
    /// // In Global.asax
    /// protected void Application_Start()
    /// {
    ///     ...
    ///     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new BreezeSimpleCorsHandler());
    ///     ...
    /// }
    /// 
    /// // In BreezeWebApiConfig
    /// public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
    ///   ...
    ///   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new BreezeSimpleCorsHandler());
    ///   ...
    /// }
    /// </example>
    public class BreezeSimpleCorsHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        const string Origin = "Origin";
        const string AccessControlRequestMethod = "Access-Control-Request-Method";
        const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
        const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
        const string AccessControlAllowMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
        const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
        const string AccessControlAllowCredentials = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(Origin);
            var isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;
            if (isCorsRequest)
            {
                if (isPreflightRequest)
                {
                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin,
                      request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

                    var accessControlRequestMethod =
                      request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
                    }

                    var requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ",
                       request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
                    }

                    response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowCredentials, "true");

                    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                    tcs.SetResult(response);
                    return tcs.Task;
                }
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    var resp = t.Result;
                    resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
                    resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowCredentials, "true");
                    return resp;
                });
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried, putting the code that's in Global.asax.cs in the BreezeWebApiConfig.cs that **does not** work.

I have tried putting this in web.config:

```
    <system.webServer>
<handlers>
</handlers>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <!-- Adding the following custom HttpHeader will help prevent CORS from stopping the Request-->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Please advice on what I am missing in the WebApi project.

Comment: I needed to open up the specific port on the server! That did it!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. FWIW, you should use the CORS support in Web API rather than the `BreezeSimpleCorsHandler` which is a relic from earlier Web API days.